# Scala - SORM not recognized

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sorm

I am doing the Play framework tutorial from https://www.playframework.com/ in Intellij.

However, on my computer, the `sorm` import is not recognized.

```
import sorm._
```

Generates

```
Cannot resolve symbol sorm.
```

I tried adding this line to `build.sbt` but this throws an error when importing.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.18"
```

The error I get is:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$66.apply(Defaults.scala:1161)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml, org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="/Users/octavian/Library/Logs/IdeaIC15/sbt.last.log">/Users/octavian/Library/Logs/IdeaIC15/sbt.last.log</a>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Is "storm" a typo? And what is the error you get after adding the line to sbt?

Comment: See https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/58